# Webservice method to return equivalent of DataSet

Tags: c#, web-services, jax-ws

Help required writing java based webservice

As per WSDL, one of the method should return System.DataSet. Not sure how I can provide java implementation?

"public ResultSet getClientDataStreamSubTypes()" is the method signatute. Instead of ResultSet I should return equivalent of System.DataSet

Any help much appreciated

Comment: And this is why webservices that are intended to be cross-platform should not use types restricted to specific language(s). :)

Comment: And out of curiousity, why are you trying to return a `DataSet` from a Java web service?  Far better (and easier) to return an object that is defined in the WSDL.  OR are you writing a Java webservice that in turn is going to consume (be the client of) a .NET web service?

Comment: I am migrating service from C# to jax-ws for different reason. While migrating came across a webmethod that returns DataSet to client. Wanted to know if there is any alternative in java without changing the client...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is - at least not easy.  In the long run it's probably better and easier to simply change the client.